How to restrict AWS Serverless ElastiCache access by the default user
I am using AWS Serverless ElastiCache (Redis) with Password authentication. I have created a new user with a password and attached specific access permissions, but the default user (default) seems to have unrestricted access.
Despite creating the new user with a secure password and access string, I am unable to remove or modify the permissions of the default user. This leaves the default user open to anyone who can authenticate, leading to security concerns.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to secure AWS Serverless ElastiCache by restricting the default user?

I missed this link in aws documention about how we can swap the default user
modify the default user with the AWS CLI
